# java 13 jar file not working in java 17 getting error UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: pluginfile (class
> file version 57.65535) was compiled with preview features that are
> unsupported. This version of the Java Runtime only recognizes preview
> features for class file version 61.65535

First I had a Java 13 production environment, later I changed to Java 17.

In Java 13, I created one jar, file name is `pluginfile` (using --enable-preview).

Now, I upgraded my Java version run using (using --enable-preview). Using `URLClassLoader` I execute the jar file.

```
URLClassLoader urlcl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { new URL(fileUrl) },
                    this.getClass().getClassLoader());
ABC hqPlugin = (ABC) urlcl
                        .loadClass("com.example.abImpl").newInstance();
```

That time I am getting this error.

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: pluginfile (class
> file version 57.65535) was compiled with preview features that are
> unsupported. This version of the Java Runtime only recognizes preview
> features for class file version 61.65535

Comment: The error message is quite clear: preview features from Java 13 are not supported in later Java releases. And you shouldn't be using preview features in production anyway (that's why they are *preview features*).  Luckily the preview features of Java 13 got turned in to real features in Java 14 and 15. So you need to recompile the source with those versions (and potentially fix any differences between the preview features and the final iteration of those features).

Comment: @JoachimSauer we didn't use preview feature in plugin jar file. only compile with enabled preview. is there any way to handle that without recompile jar file?

Answer (score 2):

Preview features for Java 13 are *only* available in Java 13. When a class is compiled with preview features enabled, it gets a minor class version of 65535. Although newer versions of Java may support the older major class version number, they intentionally do not support the "preview" minor class version of older major class versions.

To fix the problem, you will need to recompile your JAR in a newer version of Java, preferably without preview features enabled if the feature is already supported in that version. If the feature changed since the preview, you will need to address any compatibility issues. In the case the preview feature was retracted, you are out-of-luck and will need to rewrite your code entirely. That is the problem with relying on preview features for production code.

Comment: we didn't use preview feature in plugin jar file. only compile with enabled preview. is there any way to handle that without recompile jar file?

Comment: @AkashShah No, you will need to recompile. In theory you could rewrite the classes to change the minor version to 0, but it is entirely possible that this will cause problems (preview features could also change how a class is generated, thus resulting in incompatible bytecode).